# Neural Network to learn evolution equations in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, ode

I am working with the time-reversed Van der Pol equation:

[image]

and I want to create a simple Neural Network (MLP) to learn the evolution equations, ie. dx/dt. All I have are time series data that I generate with `solve_ivp` so I think I will need to use a finite difference approximation of the derivative and use this in my loss function.

This is how I create my time series:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

# Initialize integrator keywords for solve_ivp to replicate the odeint defaults
integrator_keywords = {}
integrator_keywords['rtol'] = 1e-12
integrator_keywords['method'] = 'LSODA'
integrator_keywords['atol'] = 1e-12

# Generate measurement data
dt = .01

t_train = np.arange(0, 10, dt)
x0_train = [0, 1]
t_train_span = (t_train[0], t_train[-1])
dim = 2
multiple = True

def van_der_pol(t, x, p=[1]):
    return [-x[1],  x[0] - p[0] * (1 - x[0] ** 2) * x[1]]

# (1000,2)
x_train = solve_ivp(fun = van_der_pol, 
            t_span = t_train_span, y0 = x0_train, t_eval=t_train,
             **integrator_keywords).y.T
```

I will expect to have a simple model of the form:

```py
model = Sequential([
    Dense(100, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (2,)),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])
```

but I am not even sure what my `X` and `y` should be given that I only have time series data.

A minimal example would really help, even for a simpler ODE. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is the overall aim of this? To construct a low-dimensional example or test application of ANN? To obtain something that is in some way better than solve_ivp or other ODE solvers?

Comment: maybe you should ask on similar portal for [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @LutzLehmann No the aim is to create a NN function that is able to learn how the evolution equations progress, ie. given a time series x(t), recover \dot{x(t)}. I would expect my NN to become increasingly better if I give it more data. I use solve_ivp just to create the data.

Comment: So the idea is that outside of proof-of-concept cases you have a collection of discretized solution paths, do some interpolation on them, spline or local Lagrange, get the derivative of that interpolation and then use path point as input and derivative at the same point as desired output. Train the network, and then plugging in the network as ODE function into a solver should recover the training paths.

Comment: It seems like you want to do model or system identification, which is a well-researched branch of deep learning. For instance, you can have a look at this paper: https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1517384113, or perhaps even just at physics-informed neural networks (PINNs).

Comment: Thanks @ThomasWagenaar, I ended up using two different methods, an MLP like the one I described above and SINDy. For anyone looking at how this was implemented, it is in my github [repo](https://github.com/kyrxanthos/NN_dynamical_systems/blob/master/build_DS.py).